# Convert Long java timestamp to sqlserver date

Tags: sql-server, date, to-date

I have a long java timestamp such as 1576665088205.
I need convert to date sqlserver.
What function can i use?

In oracle I used:

```
select to_date(to_char((SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( "+time+" / 1000,'SECOND' )  FROM DUAL),'DD.MM.YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') From dual
```

In postgress:

```
SELECT to_date( TO_CHAR (to_timestamp ("+time+" / 1000),'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD')
```

In sqlserver?
thanks

Comment: Can you check here ? https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23767294/convert-long-java-date-getTime-to-sql-server-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "translate" your statements using T-SQL syntax, one possible approach is to use `DATEADD()` and `DATETIMEFROMPARTS()` functions:

Statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(
   date, 
   DATEADD(second, 1576665088205/1000, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
)
```

Result:

```
2019-12-18
```